# Why doesn't this Mongoose query work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var latitude = 34
var longitude = -84

MyModel.find({
    "$and": [
       { "expiry" : { "$gt" : Date.now() } }
      ,{ "area.min-lat"   : { "$lte"  : latitude  } }
      ,{ "area.max-lat"   : { "$gte"  : latitude  } }
      ,{ "area.min-long"  : { "$lte"  : longitude } }
      ,{ "area.max-long"  : { "$gte"  : longitude } }
    ]
  }, 
  function(err, matches){
    if (!err) {
      callback(matches, null)
    } else { // there was an error
      console.log(err);
      callback(null, err);
    }
  });
```

executes without fail, but continues to return nothing. I've tried isolating the expiry and the map area parts, and neither works. Yet if I just do a `find()` or change the comparisons to a $ne, I get my result back. 
There is only one object in the database I'm trying to pull for testing...

```
"_id" : "543ee4e4e55422ab155f0a44",
    "name" : "Test Location Space",
    "img-url" : "http://s3.amazonaws.com/test/test/32098mfsnsdj09w.jpg",
    "expiry" : "2016-01-17T08:42:12.586Z",
    "area" : {
        "min-lat" : 33,
        "max-lat" : 35,
        "min-long" : -85,
        "max-long" : -83
    }
```

Comment: isolated the problem to `{ "area.max-lat"   : { "$gte"  : latitude  } }` and also `"expiry" : { "$gt" : Date.now() } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problems here were my fault, and the code is mostly correct.

First, the `latitude` and `longitude` were actually strings (as parsed by Express's default middleware). For whatever odd reason though, only the `max-lat` subquery was thrown off by the string type. Commenting that out would cause the query to return the expected result. 
My solution to that was just ensuring the parameters were indeed a float.

Next, the date for my `expiry` was just a string, when really it should have been a date type. I created a new object through Mongoose, feeding it a native Javascript date type, which was stored as `ISODate("2014-10-26T17:57:47.727Z")`. My query for `{ "expiry" : { "$gt" : Date.now() } }` now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
"expiry" : { "$gt" : Date.now() }
```

to

```
{ 'expiry' : { $gt : Date.now().toString() }}
```

You are missing `{}` around that and convert date.now to string. it works for me

Comment: I had the braces around that subquery actually, I just copied over the code while debugging. I tried a simple find (no `and`) with your code exactly, and it still doesn't work. Going to try updating MongoDB and Mongoose

Comment: remove '"expiry" : { "$gt" : Date.now() } ,', look its working or not, if its working your query doesn't work because of time comparison , convert it to string

Comment: So the date stuff is still not working (toString has no effect) - I found the problem with my map area query- my variables were actually Strings (parsed with node's body-parser). For some odd reason, only the `max-lat` query wasn't working...

Comment: Will you comment out the date subquery and set the lat and long to strings and see what the results are? I don't understand why only the max-lat sub-q would have a problem with the string type when the others don't.

Comment: my query works ---------->  fine db.test0.find(
{
    $and:
    [
       { 'expiry' : { $gt : Date.now().toString() }}
      ,{ 'area.min-lat'   : { '$lte'  : 33  } }
      ,{ 'area.max-lat'   : { '$gte'  : 35  } }
      ,{ 'area.min-long'  : { '$lte'  : -85 } }
      ,{ 'area.max-long'  : { '$gte'  : -85 } }
    ]
}
);

Comment: Copied that, not working. I'm on node 0.10.31, express 4.9.7, mongoose 3.8.17... Did you copy my JSON object over manually? Starting to think there's an incompatibility with Mongo's ISO dates and javascript's unix timestamp. (by the way, thanks for your help)

Comment: I inserted exactly your json, and did query with the code I pasted. Its odd its not working for you :(

Comment: Check my answer for an update. Its disturbing how your versions picked up the date string as a date, where mine just counted it as a string literal.